# Get rid of excess space on right side of window

Tags: html, css, centering

How can I get rid of the excess space on the right side of the browser window?

In the picture below, Firebug has highlighted my `#menuDiv` div and the white portion on the right is not part of the border for that element. So where is it coming from? Perhaps the `body`?

[image]

When I look at the body element the same way, Firebug shows that it does indeed compass the extra space on the right. But it also shows that `body` has margins and padding of 0! What's going on here? And how can I fix it so that the page is centered?

[image]

(Btw, there is some empty space at the top because I've set `body`'s height to 98% of the `html` for height sizing reasons.)

### Demo

http://tuningcode.com/practice/2014-4-24-01.html.

### Code

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Math Browser</title>
<style>
    html {
        font-family: "Cambria", "Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    }
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        height: 98%;
    }
    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .info-pane .section p {
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    div {
        padding: 5px;
        outline: none;
    }
    #browserDiv, #infoDiv {
        overflow: auto;
        max-height: 600px;
    }
    #browserDiv, #infoDiv {
        float: left;
        margin: 1%;
        height: 85%;
    }
    #browserDiv {
        width: 46%;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    #infoDiv {
        width: 46%;
        border: 1px solid #47d;
    }
    #menuDiv {
        width: 95%;
        border: 1px solid goldenrod;
        height: 25px;
        margin: 1%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #menuDiv h2.innerDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menuDiv"><h2 class="innerDiv">Math Browser</h2></div>
<div id="browserDiv"></div>
<div id="infoDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some HTML/CSS posted here as well as jsfiddle.net sample would go a long way toward the answer

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you

Comment: probably the elements INSIDE that container are too small or have padding. just because `<body>` doesn't have margins/padding doesn't mean its children can't.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to post the whole thing because my code right now is a monster of PHP and javascript, but I'll narrow it down and post a minimal example showing the same behavior.

Comment: OK, added a MWE. Code and site demo now in post.

Comment: That white space is the extra 5% of the document that's not being used by your divs. You're adding a 1% margin so the additional white space on the right is the 4% that's left over.

Use `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `margin: 1%;` to center the divs.

Comment: @APAD1 is there any way to center divs without using auto? I.e. if I want to set a particular margin but also center it? (I'm okay with using a table element if necessary.)

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius You could set the margin to 2.5% that way the margin would be 2.5% on both sides so the white space would be even, but this is effectively the same thing as using auto. I would suggest using 100% width and then setting static padding on the left and right of the container to create the margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css, `width` by default does not include padding or border, so two divs with width 48% and 1% margin will fit the width of their parent.  the moment you add any padding or border, the combined width of your inner divs will be greater than 100%.

You can do two things:

1) set the box-sizing property of css, keeping in mind that there are some [compatibility issues](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing)

```
#browserDiv, #infoDiv {
    box-sixing: border-box;
}
```

2) set the width/margin of a wrapper div, and use an inner div to set the padding/border.

```
<div class="wrapper"><div id="browserDiv"></div></div>
<div class="wrapper"><div id="infoDiv"></div></div>

.wrapper {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
#browserDiv, #infoDiv {
    padding: 5px;
}
#browserDiv {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#infoDiv {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

I'm a bit of a dinosaur, so I tend to use the latter.

Comment: I always thought it worked like this... you set `width=200px`, and `padding=5px`, and the element still has a total width of 200px, but 5 on each side of the inside is taken up by padding. This is not correct?

Comment: Also, this one has no div padding but math still doesn't add up correctly: http://tuningcode.com/practice/2014-4-24-07.html

Comment: is width=200px and padding=5px, the element would take up 210px.  Additionally, if that element has a 1px border, it would take up 212px.  Remove the borders in your linked example to get the divs side-by-side

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your sample into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvLkK/). It looks like at least part of the problem is this:

```
#menuDiv {
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid goldenrod;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The `width: 95%;` isn't working out quite right. Simply removing this seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, still not quite working for me. I made some changes, including putting all the content inside a main div so that the floats could be centered. See here: http://tuningcode.com/practice/2014-4-24-03.html. But the math somehow doesn't work out. I am giving each of the floated divs a width of 48%, and the margin is 1%. Shouldn't that be 48 + 48 + 1 (left) + 1 (middle) + 1 (right = 99%? But the div on the right side floats down below, as though it doesn't fit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your culprit:

```
#menuDiv {
    width: 95%;
}
```

using `display:block` magic (default for all `<div>`'s), you don't need to set width to get full width

Comment: My divs are floated, so not setting the width gives them a width of their content.